# Generate diff file from rsync

Tags: unix, diff, rsync

Is it possible to just generate a diff instead of generating and applying the diff using rsync? My requirement is to generate diff on one machine and apply it on another machine. Is it possible using rsync? Please note that, want to sync just one file, not an entire directory.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261372/72304

Comment: How is that different from just running the rsync as normal on another machine?

Comment: Hi @jhnc , I don't want to have a dependency over ssh port which may be blocked as well. So want to generate diff, send it to the target machine and apply diff over there.

Comment: How will you send it? What do you mean by "a diff"? How big is the file?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. rsync has a special option called "--only-write-batch=" which allows you to produce diff file without applying it to the destination file. Client will pull the diff with an HTTPS request. At the client side, I am going to apply the diff to my file using "--read-batch=".